# How to programmatically access an Eclipse JDT tooltip icon

Tags: eclipse, icons, eclipse-jdt

I'd like to use the icon "Quick Assist Available" (lightbulb) from Eclipse's [JDT Icons.](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

However, I cannot find a way to access it.

The closest I've gotten was thanks at [Ilya Shinkarenko](http://shinych.blogspot.ca/2007/05/eclipse-shared-images.html)'s blog, where he uses `ISharedImages` to access many Eclipse logos. However, the lightbulb icon is not on his list and I can't find it's proper name anywhere (I'm not even sure if it's part of `ISharedImages`).

Do you know where I can get a hold of this icon within Eclipse and use it in my own tooltip?

Answer (score 2):

Here is this in action using a Groovy script:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPluginImages;
def image = JavaPluginImages.get(JavaPluginImages.IMG_OBJS_QUICK_ASSIST)
def newView = eclipse.views.create("a button with an image");
def button = newView.add_Button().setImage(image);
```

Comment: Here is a post that shows this in action: http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/12/groovy-script-to-create-view-that-shows.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPluginImages.IMG_OBJS_QUICK_ASSIST.

A code snippet like `JavaPluginImages.get(JavaPluginImages.IMG_OBJS_QUICK_ASSIST)` should do the trick. (JavaPluginImages is not API hence you will get a warning in your code, but you can just ignore that)